# Best ways to fix outLook 2007 Error - Your mailbox is over its size limit

Tags: windows-7, windows, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, microsoft-outlook-2007

what are the best ways to fix the error "Your mailbox is over its size limit"

as I may not be able to request my SA to increase the space :)

I get a mail from system administrator saying

> "Your mailbox has exceeded one or more
>   size limits set by your administrator.
>   Your mailbox size is 218275 KB.
>   Mailbox size limits:  You will receive
>   a warning when your mailbox reaches
>   204000 KB.You may not be able to send
>   or receive new mail until you reduce
>   your mailbox size. To make more space
>   available, delete any items that you
>   are no longer using or move them to
>   your personal folder file (.pst). 
>   Items in all of your mailbox folders
>   including the Deleted Items and Sent
>   Items folders count against your size
>   limit.   You must empty the Deleted
>   Items folder after deleting items or
>   the space will not be freed. See
>   client Help for more information. "

Comment: Why is deleting not an option?

Comment: It tells you right there in the message what you should do

Comment: I wouldnt be posting this question if I could easily delete all official mails :)

Answer (score 2):

Options:

- Delete the items which are not required
- Create a separate datafile on your hard disk and move old mails to this data file.

Answer (score 1):

Use the archive feature regularly. This will move everything older than a certain date to a separate PST file that is local to your computer, and will not count against your mailbox size.

In the future, if you get stuff that you REALLY don't want, like SPAM, hold the shift key down as you delete: This will permanently delete an item. You can still recover it if you accidentally "permanently" delete something, by going to Tools>Recover Deleted Items (assuming your company is using Microsoft Exchange as its mail server).